# Adding labels to the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes of a ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am trying to get the text labels to appear along the appropriate axes. What is the correct way to do this?

```
    projects := {{4, 2, 4}, {2, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 3}, {3, 3, 3}, {4.3, 3, 
    4}, {0, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {5, 3, 4}} {4, 2, 4}, {0, 0, 0}.{5, 5, 
  5}
    ListPointPlot3D[projects, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
    PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[RGBColor[1., 0.61, 0.38], Opacity[1.], PointSize[0.03], 
    AxesLabel -> Text[{"Insight", "Scalability", "Rigour"}]]]
```

Comment: your input data produces errors (as does the plot function syntax, hint `Directive`); perhaps you should check on that; also check [`AxesLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesLabel.html); doing something like `Thread@Text[{"Insight", "Scalability", "Rigour"}]` might be helpful, although not strictly necessary; also [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html) might be helpful, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
projects={{4,2,4},{2,5,5},{4,5,3},{3,3,3},{4.3,3,4},
   {0,3,4},{1,3,4},{5,3,4}, {4,2,4},{0,0,0},{5,5,5}};

ListPointPlot3D[projects,
  PlotTheme->"Detailed",
  PlotStyle->Directive[RGBColor[1.,0.61,0.38],Opacity[1.],PointSize[0.03]],
  AxesLabel -> Flatten[Text[#] & /@ {"Insight", "Scalability", "Rigour"}],
  BaseStyle->14
]
```

Note, as commented above by  user42582, the `AxesLabel` line above can also be written as

```
AxesLabel -> Thread@Text[{"Insight", "Scalability", "Rigour"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you. Nasser, your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Clearly, I need to look into the Text function.